# How to show a text as hidden using c#

Tags: c#

I am developping in C#.
I need to capture a password written inside a Text Box, but would like to not show the password that is being typed, showing instead **** or any other character to hide the password.

How can I do that? I'm sure it's by modifying an attribute, but can't find which one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3223ht2.aspx

set the PasswordChar property of the textbox

Answer (score 1):

Set the [`PasswordChar` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.passwordchar.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

There is a property on the TextBox class called "UseSystemPasswordChar" (assuming winforms) that let you do this.

Comment: Thanks... which property? That's what I would like to know :-)

Comment: It's called UseSystemPasswordChar.

Answer (score 0):

To use your own custom character: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.passwordchar.aspx

To use the system default character:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.usesystempasswordchar.aspx

```
textBox1.UseSystemPasswordChar = true;

//or

textBox1.PasswordChar = '%';
```